# Add attachments to google calendar in someone else events

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I have an app that creates calendars in the admin account of the GSuite, then add some events with some invitation users (in order to show this event in the user's calendar).

The user can't add attachments to this event but can see the one that the app provides.

The app create the event via API and I have set to true the "supportAttachments" property.

what am I missing?

TY

Comment: Your missing a question so far you only have statments.   Please edit your question include enough code to recreate the issue and describe the issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

### You missed to give the user the permission to modify the event (viewers can not add attachments)

The method [Events:Insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) has the option to specify in the request body  `guestsCanModify:true`

[image]

Comment: In this way the user will be able to modify even the date or the location of the event. So I suppose there is no way to allow only the attachments..

Comment: I do not think there is a way to allow only attachments, see here for the possible options for attendees: https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing. As a rule of thumb - whatever you cannot do with the User Interface will not be possible via the Calendar API neither.